Ordering functions from slowest to fastest and Big Θ
I've been working on ordering a set of functions by their order of growth from slowest to fastest and grouping them by their Θ-class. Is my ordering from slowest to fastest growth correct?
Functions:

$(\lg \lg n)^2$
$20n + 5000$
$n^n$
$\lg(n!)$
$2^{2n}$
$n \ln n$
$\frac{n}{\lg \lg n}$
$(\ln n)^{1/1000}$
$n^{1.0001}$
$\lg(\lg^2 n)$
$(2n)!$
$\frac{n}{2^{100}}$

My Attempt at Ordering and Grouping:

$\lg(\lg^2 n)$
$(\lg \lg n)^2$
$(\ln n)^{1/1000}$
$\frac{n}{\lg \lg n}$
$(\frac{n}{2^{100}},\ 20n + 5000)$ (Both in Θ(n))
$(n \ln n,\ \lg(n!))$ (Both in Θ(n ln n))
$n^{1.0001}$
$2^{2n}$
$n^n$
$(2n)!$

My Reasoning:

Functions 1-3: Involve logarithmic terms with very slow growth.
Functions 4-6: Include linear and near-linear functions; constants and coefficients don't affect the Θ-class.
Function 6: $\lg(n!)$ approximated using Stirling's approximation, leading to a dominant term of $n \ln n$.
Function 10: $(2n)!$ grows faster than $n^n$ due to the factorial, which significantly increases growth rate.

Any insights or corrections would be greatly appreciated!

This looks completely correct, well done. Are you looking for proofs though? For example, justifying the order of the first 3 functions is a good exercise.

@Jan Thanks. Just to confirm, (2n)! grows faster than n^n, right? I know n^n > n!, but (2n)! involves doubling n before applying the factorial, which I think makes it grow even faster than n^n.

Putting this in an answer, because it’s a bit too long for a comment. Responding to @Gator’s comment, yes $n^n = o((2n)!)$.
We can use Stirling’s approximation, which is
$$
n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}e\right)^n \Rightarrow (2n)!\sim \sqrt{4\pi n}\left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{2n},
$$
meaning
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{4\pi n}\left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{2n}}{(2n)!} = 1.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^n}{(2n)!}= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^n}{(2n)!} \frac{\sqrt{4\pi n}\left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{2n} }{\sqrt{4\pi n}\left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{2n}}
\\= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^n}{\sqrt{4\pi n}\left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{2n}}\cdot \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{4\pi n}\left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{2n}}{(2n)!} = 0 \cdot 1= 0.
$$
The first factor in the above expression can easily be shown to be zero. In fact, investigating this limit yields $n^n = o((an)!)$ for all $a>1$.
